# Video Similarity Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, vision

Is there any way to find the similar video and duplicate video from gallery though iOS 16 has build in duplicate image finding option but is there any public api for this? I need some ideas how to find the similar videos and duplicated videos in iOS swift?

I tried to find the similar images using vision by calculation Feature Print. It can compare one by one image, I need to find out all the similar or duplicate images at a time by group.